# Magento Shipping Price calculation for back-end Edit Order

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

I am using [Amsty](https://amasty.com/shipping-table-rates.html) shipping table rate extension for shipping rate calculation.

Also am using [TinyBrick](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/true-edit-orders-2-0.html) extension for back-end order edit.

Once i edit the order in back-end, some amount ($-Grand Total) will increase.
Now that time shipping rate is not changed for current amount ($-Grand Total)  its showing old shipping rate.

(I am edit the order in back-end, After submit that page that time,  **i got $Grand Total, $country_id, $region_id, $postcode, $region, $city.** How i calculate new shipping value for new grand total.)

How to fix this issue.

Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is whenever the order is edited and then saved,it should call the amsty extension function for calculating shipping charges.